# MYSQL - Multiple Conditions in One Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores specific training criteria that is required for employees that meet a specific criteria. Their employee profile has a variety of information but the training "profiles" are largely driven by jobtitle, department, province/state, country, and project they are on.

I am trying to determine how to do the following:

- Find the first column that isn't null (will never be a situation where all columns are null)
- Check based on the values passed to it from the user profile
- If this condition is met, move to the next, remaining columns and see if the any other values match.
- If there is one match and the rest are null, return the row. If more than one column are not null then each passed value must match.

Sample table:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                      trainingProfile_tb                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| No | course_name | project_id | provinceState_id | country_id | department_id | jobTitle_id |
+----+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | Shooting    |       null |                1 |          2 |          null | null        |
| 2  | Running     |          1 |             null |       null |          null | null        |
| 3  | Shooting    |          2 |                3 |       null |             1 | null        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Let's say the employee has a project of 1, province/state of 1, country of 2, department of 1, and job title of 1.

I would want to return courses of shooting and running since what values that are in the table match the non-null values.

I hope this makes sense, but if not please let me know what needs to be clarified and I will do my best. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So this seems to have achieved the desired result. Is there a more efficient and/or elegant way of writing this?

```
SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
CASE WHEN company_id is null THEN TRUE WHEN company_id is not null and company_id=1 THEN TRUE END
AND
CASE WHEN provinceState_id is null THEN TRUE WHEN provinceState_id is not null and provinceState_id=3 THEN TRUE END
AND
CASE WHEN jobTitle_id is null THEN TRUE WHEN jobTitle_id is not null and jobTitle_id=3 THEN TRUE END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**case when** key word usually used in **select** part.
If you want fetch some data that has multiple condition and conflict, you can make some temp table like **union join** between more destributed **select**.
After that you have a table that all need data in there and make the your share conditions.
If you want the query!? Please describe more.
Regards a.ayati

Comment: Hmm, do you possibly have a sample of what you mean? I am having a hard time understanding the benefit of making another table out of the data.

Comment: Hi
please try these queries in comments. I hop these are useful

Comment: `SELECT course_name FROM requiredtraining_tb WHERE 
company_id is null or (company_id is not null and company_id=1)
and
provinceState_id is null or (provinceState_id is not null and provinceState_id=3)
and
jobTitle_id is null or (jobTitle_id is not null and jobTitle_id=3)`

Comment: SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
company_id is null or (company_id is not null and company_id=1)
union
SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
provinceState_id is null or (provinceState_id is not null and provinceState_id=3)
union
SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
jobTitle_id is null or (jobTitle_id is not null and jobTitle_id=3)

Comment: select * from 
(SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
company_id is null or (company_id is not null and company_id=1)) tbl1
inner join
(SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
provinceState_id is null or (provinceState_id is not null and provinceState_id=3)) tbl2 on tbl1.course_name = tbl2.course_name
inner join
(SELECT course_name FROM `requiredtraining_tb` WHERE 
jobTitle_id is null or (jobTitle_id is not null and jobTitle_id=3))tbl3 on tbl2.course_name = tbl3.course_name

Comment: Thanks for the thorough follow up. I like the top query the best for sure and in fact it is very similar to something I was toying around with last night. I believe it is the best answer so thanks! Here is mine too.  SELECT * FROM requiredtraining_tb WHERE (company_id is not null and company_id=1 OR company_id is null) 
AND (provinceState_id is not null and provinceState_id =1 OR provinceState_id is null)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could start with this...

```
Select No entity
    , 'course_name'  attribute
    , course_name value
From training_profile_tb
Union 
Select no
     , 'project_id'
     , project_id...
```

Comment: Can you by chance attempt to show me the functionality of this? I was under the impression that union was more to do with bringing together multiple tables. However, if it is useful here I am, of course, willing to use it.